# Extend Request.IsSecureConnection property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm actually not sure if this is possible in VB.NET, but I am trying to extend the built in property `Request.IsSecureConnection`.

I am using SSL offloading on a reverse proxy so all connections hitting the node would always return false for `Request.IsSecureConnection`. My own extension would check the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` first then fallback to the standard method if the header is not present.

Here's what I have so far, but when I set a breakpoint in here this block never gets hit. I'm sure for a very good reason.. just not sure what that reason is?

```
Module Extensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function IsSecureConnection(Request As HttpRequestBase) As Boolean
        If HttpContext.Current.Request("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO") <> "" Then
            Dim https As String = HttpContext.Current.Request("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO")
            If https.ToLower = "on" Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Else
            Return Request.IsSecureConnection '<< Not sure here how I would reference the .net framework class without looping back into this function?
        End If
    End Function

End Module
```

**EDIT:**

The reason I want to intercept this property rather than write my own custom method is because a library I am dependent on is referencing this property and I cannot override this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN says that:

> An extension method will never be called if it has the same signature
>   as a method defined in the type.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx

So I suspect you cannot achieve what you want using extension methods.

Comment: Yes I also just found this, thanks. I guess I will need to use another library.